# Getting ParserError (a custom exception), even though the conditions for the exception are not met. I've shown my code below

Tags: python

When I assign value to word_list at the by default, the program works fine. But when I assign value to word_list by getting it from use through raw_input(), I get ParserError, even though the input is correct.

I am unable to understand as to why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
def parse_subject(word_list):
    skip(word_list,'stop')
    word_type = peek(word_list)
    if word_type == 'noun':
       return match(word_list)
    elif word_type == 'verb':
        return 'player'
    else:
        raise ParserError("Expected a noun or verb next")

def parse_verb(word_list):
    skip(word_list,'stop')
    word_type = peek(word_list)
    if word_type == 'verb':
        return match(word_list)
    else:
        raise ParserError("Expected a verb next")

def parse_object(word_list):
    skip(word_list,'stop')
    word_type = peek(word_list)
    if word_type == 'noun':
        return match(word_list)
    else:
        raise ParserError("Expected a object next")


def peek(word_list):
    if word_list:
         word = word_list[0]
         return word[0]
    else:
        return None

def match(word_list):
    word = word_list.pop(0)
    return word[1]

def skip(word_list, word_type):
    if word_list:
        while peek(word_list) == word_type:
            word_list.pop(0)

class Sentence():
    def __init__(self, word_list):
        self.word_list = word_list


    def result(self):
        return parse_subject(self.word_list), parse_verb(self.word_list), parse_object(self.word_list)

word_list = [('verb', 'going'), ('stop', 'go'), ('noun', 'temple')]

Sentence_ob = Sentence(word_list)
print Sentence_ob.result()
```

Comment: That code does not give me an error in Python 2.7.11. Please show an example where you do get an unexpected error.

Comment: Please show us which input you give to the program

Comment: I gave the same value for word_list as is shown in the program.@ Roberto

Comment: This code will not... but if you try to take use raw_input() instead of giving the value of word_list at the end of the program by default, it raises ParseError.@RoryDaulton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no error while taking input through raw_input,check this way

```
def parse_subject(word_list):
    skip(word_list,'stop')
    word_type = peek(word_list)
    if word_type == 'noun':
       return match(word_list)
    elif word_type == 'verb':
        return 'player'
    else:
        raise ParserError("Expected a noun or verb next")

def parse_verb(word_list):
    skip(word_list,'stop')
    word_type = peek(word_list)
    if word_type == 'verb':
        return match(word_list)
    else:
        raise ParserError("Expected a verb next")

def parse_object(word_list):
    skip(word_list,'stop')
    word_type = peek(word_list)
    if word_type == 'noun':
        return match(word_list)
    else:
        raise ParserError("Expected a object next")


def peek(word_list):
    if word_list:
         word = word_list[0]
         return word[0]
    else:
        return None

def match(word_list):
    word = word_list.pop(0)
    return word[1]

def skip(word_list, word_type):
    if word_list:
        while peek(word_list) == word_type:
            word_list.pop(0)

class Sentence():
    def __init__(self, word_list):
        self.word_list = word_list


    def result(self):
        return parse_subject(self.word_list), parse_verb(self.word_list), parse_object(self.word_list)

#word_list = [('verb', 'going'), ('stop', 'go'), ('noun', 'temple')]
word_list=[]
for  i in range(3):
    a=raw_input("enter first value of tuple")
    b=raw_input("enter second value of tuple")
    word_list.append((a,b))    

Sentence_ob = Sentence(word_list)
print Sentence_ob.result()
```

Comment: you can change for loop according to your needs

Comment: I ran the program as you suggested... But its giving me the same error. Only happens if i try to take the value from the user. Does not raise and error if I give the value by default.

Comment: show what you did,as no error  is coming when i am trying,Please also mention how you are taking input

Comment: I finally got it!. Thanks for your help  :).

Comment: if you like answers pls like it